# debootstrap --second-stage with fakechroot fails on docker (/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory)

Tags: docker, chroot, fakeroot, fakechroot

I am trying to set up a foreign chroot in a docker container. Excerpt from the script:

```
apt-get -y install debootstrap fakechroot fakeroot qemu-user-static binfmt-support
mkdir -p $CROSS_ROOT
fakechroot fakeroot -s .fakeroot.state debootstrap --variant=fakechroot --include=fakeroot,build-essential,ca-certificates,debian-archive-keyring,git,sudo --arch=${CROSS_ARCH} --foreign ${CROSS_RELEASE} $CROSS_ROOT $CROSS_MIRROR
mkdir -p $CROSS_ROOT/usr/bin
ln /usr/bin/qemu-*-static $CROSS_ROOT/usr/bin/
fakechroot fakeroot -i .fakeroot.state -s .fakeroot.state chroot $CROSS_ROOT /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

For Debian buster/armhf, the last line fails with the following error message:

```
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
```

However, when I insert `ls -la $CROSS_ROOT/lib/ld-linux-*` before the last line, the library file is found:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Mar 15  2022 /opt/chroot/armhf/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -> arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
```

The link target also exists:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105840 Mar 15  2022 /opt/chroot/armhf/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
```

So the library is definitely where it should be. What is wrong here, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sources on the net indicate that `fakechroot` behaves in an inconsistent manner, which might explain the failures. Besides, `fakechroot` should not be needed, as `chroot` runs without any issues in a Docker container (GitLab CI runner, which as I understand runs in unprivileged mode).

On the other hand, `fakeroot` seems to be necessary, as some privileged operations (namely, mounting `/sys` and `/proc`) will otherwise fail on an unprivileged Docker container.

This also means we can select a regular `--variant` (anything other than `fakechroot`, which will error out if not running in a `fakechroot` environment).

So, drop `fakechroot` and use a `--variant` other than `fakechroot` (in my case, `buildd` as I am setting up a build system). The following worked, at least to the point that `debootstrap` finishes both stages without errors:

```
apt-get -y install debootstrap fakechroot fakeroot qemu-user-static binfmt-support
mkdir -p $CROSS_ROOT
fakeroot -s .fakeroot.state debootstrap --variant=buildd --include=fakechroot,fakeroot,build-essential,ca-certificates,debian-archive-keyring,git,sudo --arch=${CROSS_ARCH} --foreign ${CROSS_RELEASE} $CROSS_ROOT $CROSS_MIRROR
mkdir -p $CROSS_ROOT/usr/bin
ln /usr/bin/qemu-*-static $CROSS_ROOT/usr/bin/
fakeroot -i .fakeroot.state -s .fakeroot.state chroot $CROSS_ROOT /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage --verbose
```

Some packages were also changed over the previous example; I didn’t investigate if that is really necessary.